# Relational Database & MyIsam

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, innodb, myisam

Just coming out of University, I have been taught the 'right' way of designing databases. e.g. database normalisation, how to structure tables etc.

Now I am faced with something which they didn't teach me at University...

It appears that I have a choice of 2 database engines - MyISAM or InnoDB.

I know that I can build a relational database with InnoDB storage engine, however as far as I can see, I cannot build a relational database with the MyISAM storage engine as I cannot link the tables.

So - my question - And please tell me if I am just being dumb or just missing a trick...

If I can't build a relational database with MyISAM, then what is it good for? 
How do I ensure database integrity with MyISAM?
Do most people use MyISAM or INNODB?
How do I enforce constraints between two MyIsam tables?

E.g. If I am building a small online store, I will have one table for products, and one table for categories. A product must belong to 1 category. How would I build this using MyIsam?

Comment: just choose InnoDB. MyISAM is a relic of the past. Indeed you don't want to live without ACID and FKs if you can help it.

Comment: use PostgreSQL. Oracle is slowly killing MySQL, and PostgreSQL is the rising star.

Comment: But if you have to use MySQL, use InnoDB to write to (master db), and MyISAM to read from (slave db) as Inno supports transactions and keys and MyISAM supports full-text search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that the current version of MySQL will not enforce foreign key constraints that are defined on MyISAM tables, but that does not mean one cannot create *relations* between such tables (which are, after all, just a matter of holding in one table data that identifies a related record in another table): one must just be more careful to manage them properly.

If enforced ACID compliance is important to you, then InnoDB is the way to go; if you can sacrifice such compliance in return for improved performance in certain situations, then MyISAM may be worth a look.  You can even mix and match both storage engines within the same database to achieve a balance, if required.

There are a *lot* of resources discussing the pros and cons of MyISAM vs InnoDB—just search on Google (or this site) and you will find!

Comment: Maybe I am being silly, but in what case would ACID compliance not be important? How do databases like WORDPRESS database get away with not being ACID compliant?

Comment: Read only databases, perhaps?

Comment: @Gravy: As I say, sometimes performance concerns trump ACID compliance.  Personally, I lean towards using InnoDB as the rule and MyISAM as the exception--but I know that others may differ.  Wordpress actually doesn't specify a storage engine, but uses the server's default (which the DBA can customise via the [`default-storage-engine`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) option; if no default was specified, MySQL <= 5.5.4 used MyISAM whereas >= 5.5.5 uses InnoDB).

Comment: Would it be fair to say that DB purists would use InnoDB, and that people who just don't understand relational databases or just want to archive stuff would use MyISAM?

Comment: @Gravy: I don't think I'm prepared to stick my neck out on that one!  As I say, there are plenty of resources discussing the pros and cons of MyISAM vs InnoDB: I'm not even going to *try* to reproduce such here, as it has been covered many times before on SO and elsewhere.  In any event, it's probably more on-topic at [dba.se] than here.

Comment: @Gravy, Foreign keys are not a defining feature of relational databases. Data integrity constraints are of course important and useful features but a database can still be relational without FKs. In any case *no* SQL-based DBMS of any kind is truly relational. SQL is incompatible with the relational model in a number of ways.

Comment: @sqlvogel - I am by no means an SQL guru, but surely the term 'relational database' by definition means that the database is structured in such a way to recognise relationships between stored data tables / data. The means by which we recognise these relationships is by Foreign keys... Unless there is some magical method that MyISAM uses, which I am not aware of, to recognise these relationships; isn't it just useful as a data dump? Or does MyISAM rely purely on the programmer to manage the integrity of the data?

Comment: @Gravy: The term relational does not come from relationships but from [**relations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)) (e.g. tables).

Comment: @ypercube - I am just debating because this is getting interesting now... The relational database is based upon the relational model which was first thought of by Edgar Codd in the 60s. Edgar Codd argued against deviations from the fundamental principles of the relational model. Now I am aware that InnoDB is not perfect, but MyISAM is way off the mark... If you are looking to normalise to BCNF, then this is not possible with MyISAM.

Comment: @Gravy: before we continue to chat (try [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) if you like), I suggest you reread the part where it says that in the relational model, the main definition is **relations**. And tables are nothing more than instances (relation variables or relvars) of such relations.

Comment: @Gravy: I can have a foreign key in a MyISAM table without the RDBMS being aware that it is a foreign key on which a constraint must be enforced.  Suppose I have two tables, `people` and `cars`; the former has a simple `PRIMARY KEY` composed of a single column `person_id`, whilst the latter has a column `owner_id` that relates records in `cars` to the record of that car's owner in `people`.  `owner_id` *is a foreign key* (it contains keys to records in a foreign table) even though the RDBMS is unaware of the relationship and does not enforce integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The relational model was developed in 1969-1970 in order to help clarify the case for building databases that conformed to that model.  There is no particular reason why the relational model should be used to model data that is eventually going to go into a hierarchical database.   However, it might be useful to use the relational model to help describe the data as it comes out of a hierarchical database, and before it is delivered to the DBMS client.

It's important to realize that the relational model of data is a design tool, and not really an analysis tool.  The ER model of data was invented precisely for data analysis without tilting the analysis towards one particular implementation, such as a relational or SQL implementation.  In the ER model as such, there are no foreign keys.  It's important to understand that foreign keys are a feature of the solution, not a feature of the problem.

Maybe, in order to build a decent database using MyISAM, you need to relearn the correct way to build a database.  What you learned in university may have been how to build a relational database, presuming that no students would ever have to build a hierarchical database.

Caveat:  most hierarchical DBMSes have had a "relational layer" plastered on top of them, so that people who think in relational terms can use the tool without have to leave the relational model to one side.  And Relational DBMSes are "better" than non relational ones, in at least some ways.  The arguments made in 1969-1970 are still largely valid.